# error in recovering the text hidden into image

Tags: matlab

i'm working on hiding text into image.. but i'm unable to get the exact text message back.. can someone plz help me in sorting out the problem and bug my code.. the value of k i'm using is 2. here's the code below:

```
clc;
close all; clear all;
clf;
cov_img=imread('pears.png');




cov_img1 =rgb2gray(cov_img);
cov_img1=imresize(cov_img1,[256 256]);
imshow(cov_img1);

k=input('enter no of bits ');
a='In this context, cryptography, steganography and water marking schemes play a vital role in establishing secret communication through encryption, hiding and embedding secret information in digital medium respectively. ';

 b=dec2bin(double(a),8);
 c=b(:);


 d=reshape(c,[],k);


e=bin2dec(d);
[m n]=size(e);


for i=1:256;
   for j=1:256;

     S(i,j)=cov_img1(i,j)-mod(cov_img1(i,j),2^k)+e(i,:);

     j=j+1;
   end
   i=i+1;
end

figure, imshow(S,[]);


 %%Extraction

 for i=1:256;
     for j=1:256;
         E(i,j)=mod(double(S(i,j)),2^k);
         j=j+1;
     end
     i=i+1;
 end


 e1=dec2bin(E,2);

 e2=e1';

 e3=reshape(e1,[],8);

 e4=bin2dec(e3);

 e5=char(e4);

 disp(e5)

[mse psnr]=msepsnr(cov_img1,S);
 disp('PSNR value is : ');
 disp(psnr);
 disp(' db');
 disp('MSE value is');
 disp(mse);
%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Look at your for loops and test the increment method?

Comment: You should explain your code. You can't just paste the entire code and ask people to debug.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar i'm trying to hide the text into image using LSB technique.. i'm partially able to recover the hidden text from the image but its not the correct text i've embedded :(
probably i'm doing something wrong in the extraction process :(

Comment: @Austin i've seen it alot.. i also have a doubt that there is something wrong in for loops, but i'm not able to correct it.. can u please help me. :)

Comment: This code has many problems, such as indexing error if `e` has less than 256 elements, what happens if `c` can't be reshaped exactly by a `k` factor of 3, 5, 6 or 7 (padding is required), how the extraction process knows the length of `e`, the `k` value and any padding involved. I'm not sure writing out code for advising on/dealing with said problems should be within the scope of an answer here. The currently accepted answer achieves the minimally required, which is solving the stated problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the method but you will not get the full message back as e is length 872 whereas i only runs up to 256. Therefore S will not include your full message. You also don't need to do j=j+1 in a for loop in Matlab. The following works for me (even though the length of e is probably not known in the definition of e1):

```
clc;
close all; clear all;
clf;
cov_img=imread('pears.png');

cov_img1 =rgb2gray(cov_img);
cov_img1=imresize(cov_img1,[256 256]);
imshow(cov_img1);

k=2;
a='In this context, cryptography, steganography and water marking schemes play a vital role in establishing secret communication through encryption, hiding and embedding secret information in digital medium respectively. ';
b=dec2bin(double(a),8);
c=b(:);
d=reshape(c,[],k);
e=bin2dec(d);
[m n]=size(e);

Z = zeros(256);
Z(1:length(e)) = e;
for i=1:256;
   for j=1:256;

     S(i,j)=cov_img1(i,j)-mod(cov_img1(i,j),2^k)+Z(i,j);

   end

end
figure, imshow(S,[]);
 %%Extraction
 for i=1:256;
     for j=1:256;
         E(i,j)=mod(double(S(i,j)),2^k)';

     end

 end
 e1=dec2bin(E(1:length(e)),2);
 e2=e1;
 e3=reshape(e2,[],8);
 e4=bin2dec(e3);
 e5=char(e4);
disp(e5')
```

Comment: How is this code different than that in the question? Other than removing the `j = j + 1`?

Comment: In the original, every row of `S` has the same first 256 secret bits from `e`. Here, the matrix `Z` has the same size as `cov_img1` and the first `length(e)` elements hold all of the secret bits, wrapping around to the next row/column as necessary to include them all. Embedding them in `S` is trivial then.

Comment: @Schorsch, you're right that most is a copy. I initially didn't paste any code but thought it would be helpful to supply a quick solution. I wasn't going to re-write the whole thing. Thanks for answering Reti43. As a further comment the for loops are likely not necessary as all operations in the for loops only affect a single element and mod takes matrices.